Python imaplib: Is there a consistent way to authenticate/login to Outlook via IMAP?
I'm literally junior to Python programming after years of C++ and C programming, and am trying to work in using Python to save all messages & attachments from Outlook, specifically imaplib.
My experiments so far led me to understand that imaplib module could succeessly connect to an email server using the IMAP protocol over SSL when I enabled my account and password for outlook server.
I've simply written a program. The program demonstrates that imaplib module connect to the server by imaplib.IMAP4_SSL:
import imaplib

ImapPort = 993

# Connect to the server
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com", ImapPort)
# Login to the account
mail.login(email_user, email_pass)

This is a very simple process ...but the authentication fails with "Login failed" for few attempts:
> imaplib.IMAP4.error: b'LOGIN failed.'

I tried another way of looking at this  -- but I'm not sure if this is consistent -- that let program demonstrates more than one attempt:
# Connect to the server
import imaplib

import logging
import sys
import time

IMAPserver = "outlook.office365.com"
ImapPort = 993

# Configure logging to write to both file and console
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Console handler
log_handler_console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_handler_console.setFormatter(log_formatter)

# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(log_handler_console)

def connect_to_server(server, port):
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server, port)
        logging.info(f"Connected to the email server {server}.")
        return mail
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
        logging.error(f"Connection failed: {str(e)}")
        return None
    
def login_with_retries(server, port, email_user, email_pass, max_retries=30, retry_delay=5):
    for attempt in range(max_retries):
        mail = connect_to_server(server, port)
        if mail is None:
            logging.error(f"Retrying connection in {retry_delay} seconds...")
            time.sleep(retry_delay)
            continue
        try:
        
            mail.login(email_user, email_pass)
            logging.info(f"Logged into the email account {email_user}.")
            return mail  # Return the mail object if login is successful
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
            logging.error(f"LOGIN failed on attempt {attempt + 1} of {max_retries} (Retry in {retry_delay} seconds). Error: {str(e)}")
            mail.logout()  # Ensure proper logout before retrying connection
            time.sleep(retry_delay)
    logging.error("All login attempts failed. Check your email credentials and settings.")
    return None  # Return False if all attempts fail

try: 
    # Connect to server
    mail = login_with_retries(IMAPserver, ImapPort, email_user, email_pass)

    if mail is None:
        # Handle login failure
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to IMAP login after multiple attempts.")

    # Select mailbox
    mail.select("inbox")
    logging.info("Mailbox inbox folder selected.")

except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
    logging.error(f"An IMAP error occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)
    sys.exit(1)

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)
sys.exit(1)

The problem is authentication fails with "Login failed" for first few attempts and finally succeeds.
2024-09-04 10:29:34 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-09-04 10:29:38 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 1 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-09-04 10:29:43 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-09-04 10:29:47 - ERROR - LOGIN failed on attempt 2 of 30 (Retry in 5 seconds). Error: b'LOGIN failed.'
2024-09-04 10:29:52 - INFO - Connected to the email server outlook.office365.com.
2024-09-04 10:29:54 - INFO - Logged into the email account s041978@hotmail.com.
2024-09-04 10:29:54 - INFO - Mailbox inbox folder selected.

Is there a correct interpretation of why validating email credentials to log in with same account and password appears to be inconsistent by using imaplib.IMAP4_SSL?

For consistent logging in on the cloud server, you will need to implement OAUTH, perhaps using Microsoft’s MSAL library.

BLUF (Bottom Line Up Front):
Microsoft has replaced basic authentication with OAuth2 for enhanced security, breaking existing Python applications using imaplib with simple username/password logins. As a result, imaplib can no longer connect to Outlook personal accounts directly.
To address this, Python applications need to adopt OAuth2 for authentication. This guide details how I updated my script to use requests_oauthlib for OAuth2 and Microsoft Graph API to access my inbox.
Step-by-Step Guide:
1. Register Your Application in Azure:

Log in to the Azure Portal using your Microsoft account.

Register your app:

Go to Azure AD > App registrations > New registration.
Provide a name (e.g., Outlook Personal App).
Choose Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts.
Add a Redirect URI: http://localhost:8000/callback.(This is an important value. Since you need to run a localhost in your machine to perform one time account authentication.


Save the registration and note your Client ID.

Navigate to API Permissions in your app registration.

Add Microsoft Graph > Delegated permissions:

Mail.Read: To read user mail.
Mail.ReadWrite: To read and write user mail.
User.Read: To read the user profile.


Grant admin consent if required.(There is no need for it in personal email accounts)


3. Implement OAuth2 Authentication and Email Access in you Python code:
Replace imaplib with requests_oauthlib for OAuth2 support:
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import threading
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import requests

# Allow HTTP for local testing (not recommended for production)
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

# Configuration
CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  # Replace with your Application (client) ID
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/callback'
AUTH_BASE_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token'
SCOPE = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite']

# Create an OAuth2 session
oauth = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, scope=SCOPE)

# Step 1: Get the authorization URL and print it
authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(AUTH_BASE_URL)
print(f'Please go to this URL and authorize access: {authorization_url}')

# Step 2: Start a Flask server to capture the redirect response
app = Flask(__name__)
auth_code = None

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    global auth_code
    auth_code = request.url  # Capture the full URL with the authorization code
    print('Authorization code received!')

    def shutdown_server():
        func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
        if func is not None:
            func()

    threading.Thread(target=shutdown_server).start()
    return 'Authorization code received! You can close this tab.'

# Run Flask server in a separate thread
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=app.run, kwargs={'port': 8000})
server_thread.start()

# Wait for the authorization code to be set by the Flask server
while auth_code is None:
    pass

# Step 3: Fetch the access token using the captured authorization code
token = oauth.fetch_token(
    TOKEN_URL,
    authorization_response=auth_code,
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    include_client_id=True
)
print('Access token obtained successfully! Lets continue')

# Proceed with API requests or other logic

# Step 4: Use the access token to access the user's mailbox
# Retrieve the first three emails from the inbox
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}'}
response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$top=3&$select=id,from,subject,body', headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    emails = response.json().get('value', [])
    
    if emails:
        print("\nDisplaying the first three emails:\n")
        for i, email in enumerate(emails, 1):
            print(f"Email {i}:")
            print(f"  ID: {email.get('id', 'N/A')}")
            print(f"  From: {email.get('from', {}).get('emailAddress', {}).get('address', 'N/A')}")
            print(f"  Subject: {email.get('subject', 'No Subject')}")
            
            # Extract the body content and display only text (no HTML)
            body_content = email.get('body', {}).get('content', '')
            if email.get('body', {}).get('contentType', '').lower() == 'html':
                # Strip HTML tags if the content type is HTML
                from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
                body_content = BeautifulSoup(body_content, 'html.parser').get_text()
            
            print(f"  Body (Text Only): {body_content.strip()[:500]}")  # Limit to 500 chars for readability
            print("\n" + "-"*50 + "\n")
    else:
        print('No emails found.')
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch emails. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print("Response content:", response.text)


If your email_user is like aaa@outlook.com, first you can try removing the text after @, keep aaa only.
If that doesn't work, try using OAuth to connect to the mail server. Here is the hint posted on 02/02/2024.
